# Why does my immediately invoked function expression interfere with my onclick?

Tags: javascript, scope, onclick, dom-events, iife

```
(function() {
  var tasks = /* Some awesome content stored here */
  var render = '';
  for(var x = 0; x < questions.length; x+= 1) {
  render += '<p onclick="changeText(' + x +')">question[i]</p>'
 }
    function changeText(x) {
      // some fancy stuff happens here with a certain x
    }
})();
```

Why do I get the error below when trying to use an IIFE but this works just fine if I get rid of the IIFE? Isn't my **changeText()** in the same scope as everything else?

How do I fix this?

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: changeText is not defined
    at HTMLElement.onclick
```

Comment: It should work better call it from the parent attributes.  give your HTML where is `p` .?

Answer (score -1):

A function declaration creates a variable (with a value that is that function) **in the current scope**.

`onclick` attributes only have access to their own scope and the global scope.

The function inside the IIFE is out of scope.

---

The quick and dirty solution is to make `changeText` a global.

---

The clean solution, OTOH:

This is one more reason that you should avoid using onclick attributes.

Don't generate HTML by smashing strings together. Generate your DOM directly and use `addEventListener`.

```
for(var x = 0; x < questions.length; x+= 1) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("question[i]");
    p.setAttribute("data-x", x);
    p.addEventListener("click", function() { changeText(this.dataset.x); });  
    something.appendChild(p);
 }
```

---

NB: Paragraphs are not designed to be interactive controls. Adding click events to them makes them inaccessible to people who aren't (or can't) using a pointing device. You should use something designed to be clicked on (like a `<button>`) instead.

Comment: _"The clean solution"_: I disagree. You shouldn't create that click handler in the loop.

Comment: @Cerbrus Can you please explain why is it wrong to reate that click handler in the loop? Is this a matter of aesthetics or does it affect your code in anyway buy doing something like this?

Comment: @user19380947: If you've got 50 questions, you're creating 50 duplicates of that function. Just create that function _once_, outside of the loop, and pass it to `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Cerbrus If you put it outside of the loop, only one event listener will be created which is for the last paragraph. Anyway to fix that and create a listener for each paragraph that will allow you to change the function without being repetitive like in the code above?

Comment: This: `function() { changeText(this.dataset.x); }` has to be moved out of the loop. Not the whole `addEventListener` call.